# How to add a favicon to a Pelican blog?

Tags: python, favicon, pelican

I am creating a static site with Pelican and I'm confused about how to add a favicon to it.

I've seen [in the documentation](http://docs.getpelican.com/en/3.6.0/tips.html?highlight=favicon#extra-tips) that:

> You can also use the `EXTRA_PATH_METADATA` mechanism to place a
>   `favicon.ico` or `robots.txt` at the root of any site.

I don't know where to put my `favicon.ico` file and what to specify in the `EXTRA_PATH_METADATA` setting (if this is really the setting that should be used).

Answer (score 40, accepted):

In [my `pelicanconf.py`](https://github.com/textbook/textbook.github.io-source/blob/4f471147e2dee4382b5a88fafdad8cfce49baf77/pelicanconf.py#L60), I have:

```
STATIC_PATHS = [
    'images',
    'extra',  # this
]
EXTRA_PATH_METADATA = {
    'extra/custom.css': {'path': 'custom.css'},
    'extra/robots.txt': {'path': 'robots.txt'},
    'extra/favicon.ico': {'path': 'favicon.ico'},  # and this
    'extra/CNAME': {'path': 'CNAME'},
    'extra/LICENSE': {'path': 'LICENSE'},
    'extra/README': {'path': 'README'},
}
```

The structure for these extra files is then:

```
/content
    /extra
        favicon.ico
        robots.txt
```

See [the documentation](http://docs.getpelican.com/en/3.6.0/settings.html#path-metadata), which shows a similar layout.

Comment: For some reason it doesn't work. I'm testing my blog locally, using `python -m SimpleHTTPServer`. Could this be the problem?

Comment: @PauloMiraMor could you be more specific that *"doesn't work"*? Are you seeing HTTP errors for the attempt to GET `favicon.ico`? Can you look in the `output` directory, does it get put in the right place?

Comment: It is not in the `output` at all. When I reload the page ther is no favicon.

Comment: @PauloMiraMor how are you rebuilding the site?

Comment: Using `pelican content -s pelicanconf.py`

Comment: @PauloMiraMor and `favicon.ico` is definitely in `/content/extra`? If so, I'm not sure why it isn't working, unless you have other `STATIC_PATHS` and `EXTRA_PATH_METADATA`s shadowing the ones you meant to use. I suggest you create a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and ask a new question.

Comment: That was the problem. I had another `STATIC_PATHS` in my `pelicanconf.py`. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The official way @jonrsharpe described doesn't work for my page. I don't know why, it should.

I decided to put the `favicon.ico` in the `image` folder and to insert a link in `base.html` to get it work:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ SITEURL }}/images/favicon.ico?v=2" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the technique outlined on the Pelican Wiki: https://github.com/getpelican/pelican/wiki/Tips-n-Tricks#copying-faviconrobotstxt

Repeating here in case that page disappears:

- create a directory beside your `content` dir, and put all your favicon items there.
- in your `Makefile`, add `if test -d $(BASEDIR)/extra; then cp $(BASEDIR)/extra/* $(OUTPUTDIR)/; fi` to any spots that build the site (ex `publish`, `html`, etc)

Now when you build the site, everything in `extra/` will get copied to the root of `/output`.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't see the favicon while working on my site locally. As it turns out, I had to access http://127.0.0.1:8000 instead of using the local DNS http://localhost:8000. The former worked.